# Наглый, голый, нагой — однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Верно ли, что *наглый, голый, нагой* восходят к одному корню?

"Этимологический словарь современного русского языка":

> Нагой.
>   ...
>
> ...
>
> см. Наглый

Answer (score 2):

Обычно такая запись делается, если **слова имеют общий исторический корень**, поэтому информация  даётся в обеих словарных статьях. Но в данном случае  "нагой и наглый" **не считаются однокоренными**.

У слова "нагой" прослеживается **и.е. корень nog** со значением "голый",  а вот в слове "наглый" выделяют только **о.-с. основу со значением "быстрый, стремительный"**. Предполагается, что значение "нахально дерзкий" развилось только **на русской почве.**

**Происхождение о.-с. основы неясно,** есть предположение, что существовала начальная форма nalgo, в которой корень lg или log (сравнить: налечь, напасть).

Информация из словаря П.Я. Черных.